# Why does the E2362 Cannot access protected symbol TControl.Text appear?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Here is the code that causes the error:

```
procedure TfrmQuoteTemp.showData;
 begin
  lblFirstName.Text := query.FieldByName('First Name').AsString;
  lblLastName.Text := query.FieldByName('Last Name').AsString;
  lblAddress.Text := query.FieldByName('Address').AsString;
  lblTown.Text := query.FieldByName('Town').AsString;
  lblCounty.Text := query.FieldByName('County').AsString;
  lblPostcode.Text := query.FieldByName('Postcode').AsString;
  lblTelNo.Text := query.FieldByName('TelNo').AsString;
 end;
```

This error happens only with Tlabel and I cannot change their Text property at all.

Comment: VCL or FMX? It matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing a VCL-based application, the error message is quite clear - `Text` is protected (not published) in `TLabel`, which publishes the `Caption` property instead. Change your code to use that property.

```
lblFirstName.Caption := query.FieldByName('First Name').AsString;
```

For future reference, this can be seen both in the Object Inspector (which shows that the `TLabel` has a published `Caption` property and not a `Text` property) and by using Code Insight in the IDE (type `lblFirstName.` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>), which does not offer the `Text` property but shows the `Caption` property if you scroll through the choices.

(Also, as a general rule of thumb (at least in the VCL): if the control accepts user input (the user can type into it) like `TEdit` and `TMemo`, it publishes a `Text` property; if not (`TLabel` or `TButton`, for instance), it publishes `Caption` property instead. As `TLabel` does not accept user input, it publishes `Caption` and not `Text`.)

Comment: In VCL, `TLabel.Text` does exist, it is just declared as `protected`, like the error message says.  All `TControl`-derived controls have protected `Caption` **and** `Text` properties, and they both use the same getter/setter methods so they both do exactly the same thing. The trick is that some controls promote `Caption` to `published` (like `TLabel` does), and some controls publish `Text` instead (like `TEdit` does).  This is not the case in FMX. All text-based controls (derived from `TTextControl`) have a single public `Text` property.

Comment: @Remy: You're right; I phrased it poorly. Corrected, and thanks.

Comment: thanks, reading this I realized my stupid and very obvious mistake, will never repeat this in the future.